# Put JS files in react-native-web assets

Tags: react-native, expo, bundler, service-worker, react-native-web

I'm working on a react-native web project using Expo's new web feature. I'd love to statically serve some OneSignal service worker files (`OneSignalSDKUpdaterWorker.js` and `OneSignalSDKWorker.js`). I placed both files in the `/assets` folder, but when I ran `expo web:build` they didn't show up. I expect that somewhere in the bundler, it is told to ignore JS files.

Is there a configuration that will allow me to get the bundler to transfer the JS files to the build so that I can statically serve them? I know I could manually add them to the dist folder, but that would be rather inelegant.

Comment: Some kind of issue, sort of. I just want a static place to serve some plain files (json, png, etc) and would like to stick 'em under, like, `./public` (or anything).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how:

> When exporting with npx expo export, the contents of the public directory are copied into the dist/ directory. It means your app can expect to fetch these assets relative to the host URL. The most common example of this is the public/favicon.ico which is used by websites to render the tab icon.

https://docs.expo.dev/guides/customizing-metro/#static-files

Comment: We can add static files to not only to the JavaScript source file built with Expo and imported files, but we can also implement static files to be served on the web app. To do so, on the root of the source, create a new directory with the name web, and add static files into the folder like below.
/web
   ㄴweb.config
   ㄴtest.js